# Enable or Disable ng-click in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Try change condition ng-click, if lenght > 1 is clickable, esle not.

```
ng-click="filtered.length >1 ? 'false' : 'true' || showSomething($index)"
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do that

```
<a ng-click="1==1 ? test() : null">click</a>
```

Comment: It's best for me, thnx @daniel

Comment: Man I love uuuuu

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put the check inside your function:

```
$scope.showSomething = function($index){
    if(filtered.length >1){
       //your code
    }
};
```

So, the HTML becomes:

```
ng-click="showSomething($index)"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also ng-disabled, which may be helpful.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

```
<div data-ng-click="showSomething($index)" data-ng-disabled="filtered.length <=1"></div>
```

Please note though, that this does change the look/feel of the button (ie. disabled button).